# Angular is being loaded twice after 5.56 update Civi menu won't load

Tags: upgrade, menu, angular, drupal-9

*Have already cleared cache* several times and tried different browser.

This message appears twice in browser Console and menu won't load after update from 5.51 to 5.56 on D9.  Menu was working before upgrade.

```
WARNING: Tried to load AngularJS more than once.
angular.js:15697 Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/ng/btstrpd?p0=%26lt%3Bcrm-angular-js%20modules%3D%22crmDashboard%22%26gt%3B
    at angular.js:99:1
    at c (angular.js:1944:13)
    at Object.Wc [as bootstrap] (angular.js:1984:12)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (crm-angularjs-loader.js?r=HTcKBen_US:7:15)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:2903)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:846)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (crm-angularjs-loader.js?r=HTcKBen_US:6:52)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3:12369)
    at r.handle (jquery.min.js:3:9088)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3:11488)
```

This is the URL that is attempting to load:

```
https://www.site.org/libraries/civicrm/core/bower_components/angular/angular.js?r=oKGx5en_US
```

Settings

> Image Directory: [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/
> Image Upload URL: [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/
> CiviCRM Resource URL: [cms.root]/libraries/civicrm/core

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2975 there is one extra command to run after.  Have created PR for documentation https://lab.civicrm.org/documentation/docs/sysadmin/-/merge_requests/347/diffs

> composer civicrm:publish

Comment: But did that fix it for you? I had similar problems where this didn't help. Some older questions and answer suggested disabling asset caching, which did the trick.

Comment: this did fix it for me, but disabling asset caching is a not a bad choice